# set tab host on bottom of screen hide below of class layout

Tags: android

hi frnds i want to set tab host on the bottom of screen using below xml and when i implemented in my code then it hides below my class xml so how to move on from this situation...thanks my code is below...

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <TabHost
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
   </RelativeLayout>
 </TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <TabHost
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">


      <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </TabHost>
```

try this, i just put tab widget at bottom and also removed the relativeLayout.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="60dp">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/calltabs_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="63dp" android:background="@drawable/background" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Try this it seems works for me.